# Is this product minimized by the trace of the matrix: $\bar{v}.M.v$

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-equations

I need to minimize an expectation value for the Hermitian matrix $M$ and an arbitrary normalized vector $v$:

$$\min(\bar{v} Mv)$$

Here $v$ is fixed and normalized: $\bar{v} v=1$ and $\bar{v}$ is the complex conjugate of $v$ but $M$ has some free parameters inside and I need to optimize them. I thought if I minimize the trace I can minimize the desired equation because by spectral decomposition of $M=U^\dagger M_D U $

$$(\bar{v} Mv)=\bar{v'}M_D v'=\sum_m\bar{v'} mv'= \operatorname{Tr}(M)$$

Here $M_D$ is the diagonal matrix composed of eigenvalues of $M$, $v'$ is transformed vector after the spectral decomposition which will preserve the orthonormality: $\bar{v'} v=1$.

So what do you think of my derivation? Does minimization of the trace leads to the minimization of the expectation value?

Comment: Your last step is wrong: $$\sum_m \bar v' m v'\neq \operatorname{Tr} M.$$ Consider for example the vector $(1,0,0)$ and  diagonal matrix $\operatorname{diag}(0,1,1)$. The problem is that you have forgotten the subscripts of the vector components in the above expression $v_m'$

Comment: Probably the vector has no element of zero. Is it still wrong? Thanks...

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes it is wrong. It will give you the sum of square of the each element of the vector times the eigenvalue of the matrix. Should I delete the entry?

Comment: I'm not an expert in SE but in my opinion you can edit the question and ask for a way of minimizing the product. Moreover, you can say that your first idea was to minimize the trace but it is wrong.